# RabbitMQ clustering in AWS asia pacific region not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I am setting up two RabbitMQ clusters. One in US EAST and one in Asia Pacific Singapore region.
I am doing this through Cloudformation templates in AWS. The clusters are independent of each other. 
The clusters are being setup in VPC with DNS resolution enabled.

The template successfully finishes and enables clustering in US East. The same template when I execute in Asia Pacific region successfully completes but does not setup clustering among rabbitmq nodes.

I think the reason behind this is because of the Private DNS addressing difference in US East and Asia Pacific.

Clustering node 'rabbit@ip-16-0-11-237' with 'rabbit@ip-16-0-11-174' ... fails in the Asia pacific region. 
If I add the entry in /etc/hosts  --- 16.0.11.174  ip-16-0-11-174  on the EC2 instance with private IP address 16.0.11.237 . Then clustering  setup works fine.

I do not have to do add the entry in /etc/hosts in US-EAST instances and it directly works.

Any work-arounds using which I can avoid adding the entry in /etc/hosts file in Asia pacific instances and also not changing the hostname.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the cluster inside a VPC doesn’t need to modify hosts  files.

1. Does the cluster work in asia pacific if you create it manually?
2. Could you post the template?

Answer (score 0):

Santosh,

I'm not sure of your use case but I would definitely recommend using Amazon SQS. By using SQS you don't have the overhead of managing a queuing server,
1) Reduced overhead
2) Cost effective
3) Fault Tolerant

Hope this help.
Gurmeet

Comment: SQS does not guarantee FIFO because of it's distributed nature. My Application requires a FIFO queue.

Comment: RabbitMQ is FIFO,but If you absolutely need to have the order message you should include a sequential tag to reconstruct the message order at consumer side.